# Fool media player to play output of html canvas for art project

Tags: html, html5-canvas, video-streaming, html5-video

I am building an interactive art installation that will project kaleidoscope effects of photo's into a 360 degree video dome. For the interactive part my plan is to use a piece of Javascript that sends output to a html canvas element. This works like a charm.

The next issue that i need to resolve is to get this html canvas element into a video player. Is there any way i can fool a video player into playing a stream while thinking it is just a plain video file on disk?

Due to the mapping / playing software i am (unfortunately) bound to a Windows 10 machine for the playback of the video.

Answer (score 0):

`<canvas>` supports the [captureStream()](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#dfn-capturestream) method. This is still experimental at the time of writing so check browser compatibility first.

```
var stream = canvas.captureStream(25); // 25 fps frame-rate
```

You can then send the stream to a peer connection with WebRTC.

[Example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-pc/) | [Source](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/capture/canvas-pc) | 
[Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/capture-stream)

Comment: Hero.  thanks i am going to try that tonight. From the supplier of the software i understood i need to get to DirectShow eventually, at least that was his suggestion. Would i be able to do something like that also or do i need an intermediate thing?

Comment: @AntonBoutkam I need more details